# How I can write all the p/div tags to txt file

Tags: c++, qt

I need to write Qt/C++ code to extract all the p tags to write each p tag to .txt file, For example if I have the following HTML page:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
         <body>

         <h1>My First Heading</h1>

         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My second paragraph.</p>

         </body>
          </html>
```

I need the code to create 2 .txt file the first one will include My first paragraph. and the second will include My second paragraph.

my problem how to parse the html and get the txt between the tags, here my code

```
         int main(int argc, char *argv[])
           {
            QApplication a(argc, argv);

              QWebPage page;
              QWebFrame * frame =page.mainFrame();
               QUrl fileUrl ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank");
                frame->setUrl(fileUrl);
                QWebElement document = frame->documentElement();
            QWebElementCollection collection = document.findAll("p");

             foreach (QWebElement paraElement, collection) {

              }



                  MainWindow w;
                 w.show();

             return a.exec();
           }
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: What about nested <p> tags. For example:
<p>This is first<p>This is a nested para with para2.</p> para.</p>
What should be your output in the above situation.?

Comment: If you're scraping Wikipedia, there are probably easier ways to do that. For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185288/how-to-get-wikipedia-content-using-wikipedia-api

Answer (score 0):

This is very naive implementation of your requirement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256 
//assuming flush means just printing 
//the <p> tags on the console.
void flushqueue(queue<string>& qtags){
  while(!qtags.empty()){

    cout <<std::endl << qtags.front() <<std::endl;
    qtags.pop();
  }
}
#define STAGSIZE 3
#define ETAGSIZE 4
const char *stag = "<p>";
const char *etag = "</p>";

void process(const string& instr,vector< pair<size_t,size_t> >& vectags){
    size_t  index = 0;
    pair<size_t,size_t>res(-1,-1);
    while(index !=string::npos  && index < instr.length()){
      res.first = -1;
      res.second = -1;
      index = instr.find(stag,index);
      if(index != string::npos){
    index+=STAGSIZE;
    res.first = index;
      }
      index = instr.find(etag,index);
      if(index != string::npos){
    res.second = index-1;
    index +=ETAGSIZE;
      }
      if(res.first !=-1 || res.second != -1)
    vectags.push_back(res);
    }
  }

int readptags(const char* filename){
  std::ifstream ifs (filename);
  queue<string>qbuffer;
  vector<pair<size_t,size_t> >vtags;
  string stag;
  while(ifs.good()){
    string temp;
    getline(ifs,temp);
    vtags.clear();
    process(temp,vtags);
    for(int i=0;i<vtags.size();i++){
      pair<size_t,size_t>res = vtags[i];
      if(res.first!=-1 && res.second !=-1){
    //a full string
    qbuffer.push(string(temp.begin()+res.first,temp.begin()+res.second+1));
      }else if(res.first==-1 && res.second !=-1){
    stag+=string(temp.begin(),temp.begin()+res.second+1) ;
    qbuffer.push(stag);
    stag.clear();
      }else if(res.first!=-1 && res.second ==-1){
    stag += string(temp.begin()+res.first,temp.end());
      }else{
    continue;
      }
    }
    if(qbuffer.size()>=BUFFER_SIZE)
      flushqueue(qbuffer);
  }
  flushqueue(qbuffer);
}
  int main(){
    //readptags("prac.html");
  }
```