# Get brief content from Wikipedia by a Java Program

Tags: java, search, wikipedia, information-retrieval, extract

Okay, so I am writing a Java program which requires me to search the web and display data. As every smart individual would do, the best place to search for information is Wikipedia.

I did some looking around and found MediaWiki, but I have no idea where to start. I'll explain what I need, and all help is appreciated!

Example:
User input: Who is Ed Sheeran?
**(leave the extracting part to me, I know how to do that)**

In the background, the program searches Wikipedia pages for Ed Sheeran, and extracts the first few sentences about him. And then, it extracts information and print it back.

So, after the program is made, this will be my output:
User input: Who is Ed Sheeran?
Output: Edward Christopher "Ed" Sheeran (born 17 February 1991) is an English singer-songwriter and occasional actor.

User input: Where is Bangalore?
Output: Bangalore /bæŋɡəˈlɔːr/, officially known as Bengaluru ([ˈbeŋɡəɭuːɾu]), is the capital of the Indian state of Karnataka.

All help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked wikimedia's web [API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page)? Probably get data from their API, then analyze text from the results of your request.

Comment: Okay, I am a beginner in this and have absolutely NO CLUE what so ever where to start. Can someone write an answer for a person who wants to start from scratch?

Comment: This is way too broad. This cannot be reasonably answered in this format. Please break this down in to discrete chunks -- designing UI, analyzing/cleaning user input, making queries to Wikipedia, consuming and formatting received data, outputting data, etc. and start on each bit. Come back when you have specific question. It seems that all you've done so far is define requirements and then just give them to us.

Comment: That's right. I have done the designing UI, analyzing/cleaning user input part. I store the search term in a string. Now the part where I need help is on making queries to Wikipedia , consuming and formatting received data. Once, I have gotten the correct page, I want to display the first sentence of the Summary text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185288/how-to-get-wikipedia-content-using-wikipedias-api

Comment: Unfortunately requests like "teach me how to make a query and consume the response" are off-topic/too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me with that query:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
```

. . .

```
String subject = "Ed Sheeran";
URL url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=raw&title=" + subject.replace(" ", "_"));
String text = "";
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()))) {
    String line = null;
    while (null != (line = br.readLine())) {
        line = line.trim();
        if (!line.startsWith("|")
                && !line.startsWith("{")
                && !line.startsWith("}")
                && !line.startsWith("<center>")
                && !line.startsWith("---")) {
            text += line;
        }
        if (text.length() > 200) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("text = " + text);
```

prints:

> text = '''Edward Christopher''' "'''Ed'''" '''Sheeran''' (born 17 February 1991) is an English singer-songwriter and occasional actor. Born in [[Hebden Bridge]], West Yorkshire and raised in [[Framlingham]],

For other queries you will probably need some trial and error to clean out extra stuff from their content.

**Update**

Here is an alternative that parses JSON with the library here:
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.json|json|20150729|jar

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

...

```
String subject = "Ed Sheeran";
URL url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exsentences=1&exintro=&explaintext=&exsectionformat=plain&titles=" + subject.replace(" ", "%20"));
String text = "";
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()))) {
    String line = null;
    while (null != (line = br.readLine())) {
        line = line.trim();
        if (true) {
            text += line;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("text = " + text);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(text);
JSONObject query = json.getJSONObject("query");
JSONObject pages = query.getJSONObject("pages");
for(String key: pages.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("key = " + key);
    JSONObject page = pages.getJSONObject(key);
    String extract = page.getString("extract");
    System.out.println("extract = " + extract);
}
```

Output:

> extract = Edward Christopher "Ed" Sheeran (born 17 February 1991) is an English singer-songwriter and occasional actor.

Comment: What are the packages you are importing for this program?

Comment: This works. But I thought of using the mediaWiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exsentences=1&exintro=&explaintext=&exsectionformat=plain&titles=Ed%20Sheeran

Comment: Also, is it possible to read the json from the above URL and print the "extract". I think that would be easier. Right?

Comment: Yes. I know there are a bunch of 3rd party json libraries to parse the json text that you could retrieve with code like the above. Unfortunately,  I am not that familiar with any of them.

Comment: Updated answer with one JSON library I found.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I tried a lot of ways and it didn't work. Hopefully this will work. What is the output?

Comment: added output for update

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. :)