# How to get full article as text using Wikipedia API?

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api

I'm using this code to fetch the article, but it contain only snipets of text:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?",
  data: {
    action: 'query',
    list: 'search',
    srsearch: "Richard Stallman",
    format: 'json'
  },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data){
      var datatp = '';
      data.query.search.map(function(f) {
          datatp += '<h3>' + f.title + '</h3>';
          datatp += f.snippet;
        });
      resultDiv.html(datatp);
    }
});
```

I found this question: [How to get Wikipedia content using Wikipedia's API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185288/how-to-get-wikipedia-content-using-wikipedias-api) but it show how to fetch first paragraph of the article in wiki markup. How can I fetch full article as text? I can live with wiki content I can figure out how to remove it from the text. [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/bo17uuov/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take the answer from that question, and leave out the specific *rvsection* argument. For example,

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=pizza

Comment: It's already left out, instead add the rvsection as parameter with value 0 ;)

Comment: No, rvsection=0 retrieves the first section. That's why I explicitly left it out in the sample URL above.

Comment: rvsection=1 retrieves the first section and rvsection=0 doesn't as far I can see.

Comment: I gave a sample link for a reason. If you *click it*, you'll see that you get the -full content- of the Wikipedia pizza article. Are you saying the link above does not work for you?

Comment: Hmm then why is his code not working? Maybe rvprop=content? Or he might need to do a separate query for each search result.