# extract specific data from wikipedia api

Tags: php, json, wikipedia-api, data-extraction

I have got a API response as below.
I this this to deode the response. and got below response.
`$data = json_decode($response);`

```
{#240 ▼
  +"batchcomplete": ""
  +"query": {#243 ▼
    +"pages": {#234 ▼
      +"171166": {#245 ▼
        +"pageid": 171166
        +"ns": 0
        +"title": "Nepal"
        +"extract": """
          Nepal (/nəˈpɔːl/; Nepali: नेपाल  Nepāl [neˈpal]), officially the Federal Democratic Republic of Nepal (Nepali: सङ्घीय लोकतान्त्रिक गणतन्त्र नेपाल Sanghiya Loktā ▶
          The territory of Nepal has a recorded history since the Neolithic age. The name "Nepal" is first recorded in texts from the Vedic Age, the era which founded Hin ▶
          Modern Nepal is a federal secular parliamentary republic. It has seven states. Nepal is a developing nation, ranking 144th on the Human Development Index (HDI)  ▶
          Nepal's foreign relations expanded after the Anglo-Nepal Treaty of 1923, which was recognized by the League of Nations. After a Soviet veto in 1949, Nepal was a ▶
          """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**I want to extract `title` and `content`. How may I do that?**

**Edit**: I have tried `$data = json_decode($response, true);` and get below result by doing this `var_dump($data['query']['pages'])`. Results:

```
array:1 [▼
  171166 => array:4 [▼
    "pageid" => 171166
    "ns" => 0
    "title" => "Nepal"
    "extract" => """
      Nepal (/nəˈpɔːl/; Nepali: नेपाल  Nepāl [neˈpal]), officially the Federal Democratic Republic of Nepal (Nepali: सङ्घीय लोकतान्त्रिक गणतन्त्र नेपाल Sanghiya Loktā ▶
      The territory of Nepal has a recorded history since the Neolithic age. The name "Nepal" is first recorded in texts from the Vedic Age, the era which founded Hin ▶
      Modern Nepal is a federal secular parliamentary republic. It has seven states. Nepal is a developing nation, ranking 144th on the Human Development Index (HDI)  ▶
      Nepal's foreign relations expanded after the Anglo-Nepal Treaty of 1923, which was recognized by the League of Nations. After a Soviet veto in 1949, Nepal was a ▶
      """
  ]
]
```

Comment: remove image and paste code....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185288/how-to-get-wikipedia-content-using-wikipedias-api

Comment: It doesn't answer my question @Ahmad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Wikipedia content using Wikipedia's API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185288/how-to-get-wikipedia-content-using-wikipedias-api)

Comment: Dear All, These answers show how to execute wiki api, but my question is to retrieve data after executing wiki api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use pages as array:

```
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=Stack%20Overflow'));

$pages = (array) $response ->query->pages;
foreach ($pages as $id => $page) {
  echo $page->title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `formatversion=2` to get the data in an easier to handle format.

```
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&formatversion=2&exintro=&titles=Stack%20Overflow'), true);
echo($response['query']['pages'][0]['title']);
```