# MIME type ('text/html') is not executable Wiki Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp, wikipedia

I try to get articles from Wikipedia using $.ajax method, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my request... When I'm proceeding I'm getting "MIME type ('text/html') is not executable" error. 
I put my code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function() {
          var text = $('input').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch="+text,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (response){
            var articles = response.query.search;
     for (var i = 0; i < articles; i++){
       var article = articles[i];
       var title = article.title;
       var snippet = article.snippet;
       var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + title;
          $('#display-result').append('<p>'+'<a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>'+'</p>');
     }
  } 
            });
        });
    });
```

I have to use JSONP data type because of Wikipedia rules, but I think that's why I can't get response. Maybe something wrong with my code...

Will be glad for your help!

Comment: You know [wikipedia provide an API right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185288/how-to-get-wikipedia-content-using-wikipedias-api)? This is to stop people using bots to crawl them (like your doing)

Comment: I'm not using bots, I just try to get any response from Wiki and for now I haven't succeed..