# How to get plain html content with images from wikipedia API

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am trying to get html content with all images from wikipeida using wikipeida's official API. Currently, The api i use only return html content

**This is what i am Using**

```js
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=google&format=json&origin=*
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185288/how-can-i-get-wikipedia-content-using-wikipedias-api

Answer (score 2):

You can get text and images using the following query example

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=text|images&page=google&format=json&origin=*
```

Then for each image, you can get the url, which can be used to download the image. For example

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=imageinfo&titles=File%3ASemi-protection-shackle.svg&iiprop=url
```

Another example to get urls for all images on a page

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=imageinfo&rawcontinue=1&titles=google&generator=images&iiprop=url
```