# Is there a way to fetch Wikipedia/Wiktionary HTML only for the main article body?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

A decade or more ago I used to do quite a bit of hacking on Wiktionary and MediaWiki. I seem to remember that I used to use some method to get the HTML of a page without most of the interface like menus, sidebars, header, footer etc.

I thought it was just done with special HTML parameters, much like the `raw` and `printable`, but I can't seem to find it in [the URL help page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:URL).

It could be that my memory isn't accurate and maybe I used [the old API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page).

This was a boon for doing things with text corpuses such as playing with Markov chains, and also for trying to parse the Wiktionary format, etc. I used to grab this version and convert to plain text or use an HTML parser etc.

One thing I seem to remember that might help is that it didn't remove *all* of the unwanted stuff. For instance I think it retained the Table of Contents. But it got rid of the vast majority of it.

Does anyone know if there's a URL parameter for this, or know what I might've been doing back in the day? If not, a method using the old API or the new REST API would be of interest.

What did I try?
I used Google, I searched here on StackOverflow, I racked my brain, and I hunted for the URL parameter documentation.

What did I expect?
I expected to remember what I used to do, or to find the old way I used to do it documented, or a new way that achieved the same end.

Comment: Why don't you get a database dump?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get plain html content with images from wikipedia API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70300206/how-to-get-plain-html-content-with-images-from-wikipedia-api)

Comment: @AlexanderMashin I've got an external hard drive full of database dumps, but they're not in HTML, and it's not always what I want.

Comment: @InSync I did find the question when I was hunting and the part about images and the fact it used the API was enough for me to skip over it, but it actually looks like it does return the exact same data in the same format in `parse.text['*']` as Tgr's answer, which is the method I used to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `raw`, try `render`. (The relevant documentation is [Parameters to index.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php).) Although for serious use I'd recommend using the API instead.

Comment: Yes! I actually remembered it/figured it out again not long after giving up and posting this question, but it's always fun to see if somebody knows the answer before answering it myself. I was looking at the other URL documentation I linked which only mentions `action=render` in passing, with zero details, but it must've been enough to nudge my memory and even after successfully testing it I noticed it was hard to Google so this Q & A should make it easier to find if anyone else needs it in the future. Thanks!