# Extracting information from wikipedia

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

for this wikipedia site: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population, how would i extract population number and percentage for china and india, although they are in one row? It needs to be in python. I was able to extract the right population for other countries except India.

my code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def load_population_dict(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    population_dict = {}
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable'})
    rows = table.find_all('tr')[1:]  # Skip the header row
    
    for row in rows:
        data = row.find_all('td')
        country = data[1].text.strip()
        population = data[2].text.strip()
        population_dict[country] = (population, data[3].text.strip())  # Store population and percentage as a tuple
    
    return population_dict
```

Comment: Wikipedia provides databases and APIs and there are rehost services which digest this.  You're making your life unnecessarily difficult reaching for scraping first.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185288/how-can-i-get-wikipedia-content-using-wikipedias-api https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to check how many cells has current row and adjust the extracting accordingly:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def load_population_dict(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    population_dict = {}
    table = soup.find("table", {"class": "wikitable"})
    rows = table.find_all("tr")[1:]  # Skip the header row

    for row in rows:
        data = row.find_all("td")

        country_idx, population_idx, pct_idx = 1, 2, 3
        if len(data) == 6:
            country_idx, population_idx, pct_idx = 0, 1, 2

        country = data[country_idx].text.strip()
        population = data[population_idx].text.strip()

        population_dict[country] = (
            population,
            data[pct_idx].text.strip(),
        )

    return population_dict


url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population"
out = load_population_dict(url)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "World": ("8,092,488,000", "100%"),
    "China": ("1,409,670,000", "17.4%"),
    "India": ("1,392,329,000", "17.2%"),
    "United States": ("335,893,238", "4.2%"),
    "Indonesia": ("279,118,866", "3.4%"),
    "Pakistan": ("241,499,431", "3.0%"),
    "Nigeria": ("216,783,381", "2.7%"),
    "Brazil": ("203,080,756", "2.5%"),
    "Bangladesh": ("169,828,911", "2.1%"),
    "Russia": ("146,424,729", "1.8%"),
    "Mexico": ("129,406,736", "1.6%"),
    "Japan": ("124,090,000", "1.5%"),
    "Philippines": ("112,892,781", "1.4%"),
    "Ethiopia": ("107,334,000", "1.3%"),
    "Egypt": ("104,462,545", "1.3%"),
    "Vietnam": ("100,300,000", "1.2%"),

...
```

Answer (score 2):

@Andrej Kesely already has a very good solution for the treatment of the `rowspan` that leads to the observed behaviour, which refers to the direct use of `BeautifulSoup` according to your question.

---

Just in addition - If you want to scrape tables, give `pandas` a chance and see how far a single line of code gets you. In my experience, the results are already sufficient in 95% of use cases.

Let's see how it looks in your case - [`pandas.read_html(YOUR URL)[TABLE INDEX\]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) already delivers an almost clean dataframe which also respects the `rowspan`.

To get to your `dict` we can now take the following steps:

- read the table by index
- select the columns to work with e.g. with `iloc[]`
- set Location column to index, to generate the keys from
- transpose the table to get a column of values for each key / country
- convert the tranposed table to dict

###### Example

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population')[0]\
.iloc[:,1:4]\
.set_index('Location')\
.T\
.to_dict('list')
```