# scraper on wikipedia: deprecated methods - removed from pandas in a future version

Tags: python, bash, web-scraping

this is one of my first steps in webscraping so i need to have some hints and tips: note i love to scrape on Wikipage.

btw: probably i gonna make use of this:
[How can I get Wikipedia content using Wikipedia's API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185288/how-can-i-get-wikipedia-content-using-wikipedias-api)

**my project: **Using the contents and beautiful soup load the data from the wikipedia site#.

well: by market capitalization table into a pandas dataframe. The dataframe should have the bank Name and Market Cap (US$ Billion) as column names. Display the first five rows using head.

But at the moment  i still want to do some extra.things - i .e. gather  a bit more of data - and the  market capitalization is not important to me. i do not need this - but i need

a. the name of the bank and

b. the website

so i will need to take care  for those data:

**Scraping the Data**

addtional idea: Using the contents and beautiful soup load the data from the By market capitalization table into a pandas dataframe. The dataframe should have the bank Name and Market Cap (US$ Billion) as column names. Display the first five rows using head. Note: very important  - the name and the website: i am going to make make usage of bs and pandas.

**Using BeautifulSoup parse the contents of the webpage.**

well i think i try  out the setup. The dataframe should has the bank Name and Market Cap (US$ Billion) as column names. i am using the empty dataframe data and the given loop extract the necessary data from each row and append it to the empty dataframe.

well i need to take care for the data

```
# Imports
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

# URL of the Wikipedia page listing largest banks
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_banks"

# Fetch HTML content of the webpage
html_data = requests.get(url).text

# Parse HTML content using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')

# Find the table containing bank data
table = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable')

# Check if the table is found
if table is not None:
    # Initialize an empty DataFrame to store bank data
    data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Bank", "Market Cap (US$ Billion)"])

    # Extract data from each row of the table
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:  # Skip the header row
        columns = row.find_all('td')
        if len(columns) >= 3:  # Ensure there are at least three columns
            bank_name = columns[0].text.strip()
            market_cap = columns[2].text.strip()
            data = data.append({'Bank': bank_name, 'Market Cap (US$ Billion)': market_cap}, ignore_index=True)

    # Display the first five rows of the DataFrame
    print(data.head()
    
    
    
Usually we will Load the pandas dataframe created above into a JSON named bank_market_cap.json using the to_json() function, 
but this time the data will be sent to another team who will split the data file into two files and inspect it.  If we inspect the data it will interfere with the next part of the assignment.


    # Save the DataFrame to a JSON file (if needed)
    data_to_json = data.to_json(orient='records')

    with open('largest_banks_market_cap.json', 'w') as f:

        f.write(data_to_json)
else:
    print("Table not found. Please check if the class name of the table is correct or if the page structure has changed.")
```

see the output

```
  Bank Market Cap (US$ Billion)
0    1                   491.76
1    2                   266.45
2    3                   219.45
3    4                   178.74
4    5       





<ipython-input-7-29fe9d42d044>:29: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  data = data.append({'Bank': bank_name, 'Market Cap (US$ Billion)': market_cap}, ignore_index=True)
<ipython-input-7-29fe9d42d044>:29: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  data = data.append({'Bank': bank_name, 'Market Cap (US$ Billion)': market_cap}, ignore_index=True)
<ipython-input-7-29fe9d42d044>:29: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  data = data.append({'Bank': bank_name, 'Market Cap (US$ Billion)': market_cap}, ignore_index=True)
<ipython-input-7-29fe9d42d044>:29: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  data = data.append({'Bank': bank_name, 'Market Cap (US$ Billion)': market_cap}, ignore_index=True)
<ipython-input-7-29fe9d42d044>:29: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  data = data.append({'Bank': bank_name, 'Market Cap (US$ Billion)': market_cap}, ignore_index=True)
<ipython-input-7-29fe9d42d044>:29: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  data = data.append({'Bank': bank_name, 'Market Cap (US$ Billion)': market_cap}, ignore_index=True)
<ipython-input-7-29fe9d42d044>:29: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  data = data.append({'Bank': bank_name, 'Market Cap (US$ Billion)': market_cap}, ignore_index=True)
<ipython-input-7-29fe9d42d044>:29: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  data = data.append({'Bank': bank_name, 'Market Cap (US$ Billion)': market_cap}, ignore_index=True)
<ipython-input-7-29fe9d42d044>:29: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  data = data.append({'Bank': bank_name, 'Market Cap (US$ Billion)': market_cap}, ignore_index=True)
<ipython-input-7-29fe9d42d044>:29: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  data = data.append({'Bank': bank_name, 'Market Cap (US$ Billion)': market_cap}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Did you read the warning message?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with scraping, it's due to how you're using pandas.

Comment: What does this have to do with `bash`?

Comment: Aside: Wikipedia has an API. Have you considered using that instead of web scraping?

Comment: howdy - no i did not use the api -  but i am willing to do so Sir

Comment: btw: probably i gonna make use of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185288/how-can-i-get-wikipedia-content-using-wikipedias-api